# unix script to extract values in xml file

Tags: unix

I have an `XML` file as below:

```
<xml>Workinstance name="suvi" permission="read" id="6543"</xml>
<xml>Projectinstance name="ram" permission="write" id="3534"</xml>
```

I want to display the workinstance id field from that `XML` file.

Comment: That does not look like XML. Rather an arbitrary format encapsulated in totally useless `<xml>` "tags". Is that real sample?

Comment: That was not the original example. I just gave this randomly.

Comment: Well, it's important to know whether the actual data is so brain-damaged, or just your sample is.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '<xml>Workinstance' file.xml | grep -o 'id="[^"]*' | cut -c5-
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/Workinstance/{ gsub(/.*id=\042|\042.*/,""); print  } ' file
6543
```