# How to grep value from a line in Unix

Tags: unix

Suppose I have a lines as follows:

```
<Instance name="cd" id="sa1">
<work id="23" permission="r">
```

I want to get the id value printed, where the id field is not constant.

Comment: What did you try?  Did you read the *grep* manpage?

Comment: you asked similar questions a few days back.. What did you do since then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170386/script-to-extract-the-details-from-xml and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157432/unix-script-to-extract-values-in-xml-file. It basically shows you are too lazy ...

Comment: you've got good answers already for your other similar questions. You should accept some.

Answer (score 1):

It hard to give a hint without *doing it for you*. But assuming your real needs are more involved than you describe, then perhaps some learning can happen while applying this answer.

Grep isn't really powerful enough to do the job you describe, although it may be useful in a pipline to select data at a larger "grain".  If your file has one-tag-per-line like your example shows, you can use grep to filter just the `Instance` or `work` tags.

```
grep Instance | program to extract id val
```

or

```
grep work| program to extract id val
```

To extract the value you need something more powerful than grep. Assuming the value is enclosed in double-quotes and contains no embedded quotes; and that there are no similarly named attributes that could confuse the expression, this sed magic should do the trick.

```
sed 's/.*id="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

If any one the above asumptions are not true, the expression will have to be more complicated.

Comment: @ghostdog74, crap! you're right. Yours is a fine answer! He should accept that move on.